# iOS Different navigation bar color on different pages

Tags: ios, objective-c, colors, navigationbar

How would I change the **navigation** bar **color** **based** on what **page** the user is on?

I would like to do something similar to what the Vine app uses in the explore category when the user taps a certain category and it turns into the color of the button in a fading format. Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: You can see the answer on the below link https://stackoverflow.com/a/64598661/11280037

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to set the navigation bar tint color in the prepareForSegue: method (in your controller whit the four buttons) like this

`- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:"segueIdentifier here"]) {
      [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
 }
}`

Don't forget to reset the navigation bar tint color when you came back (do this in the viewWillAppear)

Or you can try to do this in all your controllers in the method viewWillAppear: like this

`- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
       [super viewWillAppear:animated];
       [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}`

Comment: Where is the prepareForSegue method located?  Also, I checked my ViewController.m and didn't see a viewWillAppear method, should I create one and if so how?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes you should create the viewwillappear method and call [super viewWillAppear:animated] in it. The prepareForSegue method is located in the viewController but how do you push the next controller?

Comment: I am using a navigation controller and I tried to change the class file for the next page and it causes it to crash when ever the button is clicked.  Any thoughts on this as well?

Comment: Can you add some code and explain what you are doing?

Comment: I have my pages embedded in a Navigation Controller (in the storyboard).  As i'm sure you know that puts a Navigation bar on the views.  I can change the color and all that on the navigationController page on storyboard, but I want that to change when a certain page is opened.  How would I specifically do this?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your storyboard? What do you call "page"? How do you go from one page to another?

Comment: Ok thanks so you should have 4 segue identifiers. I will edit my answer to give you a solution

Comment: Should I put the prepareForSegue in the ViewController or should I make a seperate class for the home page?

Comment: In the viewController where your four buttons are

Comment: In the storyboard you should have put segue identifier in the properties of each segue you've created. (you should use this one). A segue identifier is just a string that identify the segue look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles-storyboard/StoryboardSegue.html) for more information

Comment: Also, just for reference I believe before the isEqualToString needs an @ before it

Comment: Yes but I wanted to create an error here. In that way you won't forget to replace this string

Comment: Any thoughts on how I would be able to do a fade or delay so it's not such a quick switch? and my apologizes I deleted it after I posted it because I found an answer.

Comment: try to put your color change in UIView animateWithDuration:

Comment: so would I move the prepareForSegue into the animateWithDuration?

Comment: I don't want to be rude but you should learn objective-c and iOS development before trying something like this. You will find a lot of tutorial on the web. You should do that :

 `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:"Your segue ID"]) {

       [UIView animateWithDuration:.2 animations:^{

        // set the navigation bar tint color here
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}]; 

    }

}`

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into finding a tutorial

Comment: You're welcome. Here are [Apple tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH2-SW1) it can be useful

Answer (score 2):

Solution for **Swift 3.0** (tested on iOS 10)

Hi! I faced the same problem and finally I've found good solution.

Setting the navigation bar's color in *viewWillAppear* method works fine when you push from a parent to a child view. Transition between navigation bars colors is smooth.

```
class ChildViewController: UIViewController {

...

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
    }
```

But it didn't really worked for setting the bar's color in the **ParentViewController** to the original one. You could notice the color's change, that looked just ugly and unprofessional.

To make the color change smooth when coming back to ParentViewController, do it within the method  *willMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?)* in your **ChildViewController**:

```
class ChildViewController: UIViewController {

...

override func willMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?) {
     self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red
```

Thanks to this approach you can set different navigation bar colors on different pages in the one Navigation Controller with smooth colors transitions between view in both ways - going to a child view and also coming back to parent.

Comment: Approach is just right, tho parent view's navbar still overlaps the child and there's navbar blinking glitch when you swipe the child to move back.

Answer (score 0):

This is the swift version of how to change navigation bar color on different pages.

You can write this line of code in the `viewDidLoad()` method of any view controller in which you want to change the color of navigation bar.

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
```

and then you can use the method ***viewWillAppear()*** method so that when you come back to the same view controller from another different controller the color remains same

```
viewWillAppear(){
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4+

```
super.viewDidLoad()

    let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "B",
    style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: "backAction")
        navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = newBackButton
    newBackButton.tintColor = .red
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func backAction() -> Void {
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

[image: this is the result]