# How can I change the backBarButtonItem colour in Swift?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem, backbarbuttonitem

I am trying to change the default backBarButtonItem colour to white colour,

my codes look like below

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

But It is not working for me, any ideas?

Comment: Have you even searched or googled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the backBarButton do this :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "B",
    style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: "backAction")
        navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = newBackButton
    newBackButton.tintColor = .red
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func backAction() -> Void {
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

[image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EFxy.png)

See the result:
[image: see the result]

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

`self.navigationController?.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.red`