# How I can implement Smooth UINavigationBar color change transition in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

I'm trying to make the `UINavigationBar` color transition smooth. 
I've looked around and I'm using ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40549764/4427884)) approach.

In the `ChildViewController` I have below mentioned code:

```
//Transition to transparent navbar
        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }

// Transition to default Navbar
        override func willMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?) {
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .default
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .default)
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = nil
        }
```

Resultant has flicker effect when swiped slowly from `ChildViewController` to `parent`

[image]

Comment: Do you need to animate to the transparent navbar?

Comment: Flicker is the issue! Check out the gif.

Comment: Check this post may helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39835420/navigationbar-delay-updating-bartintcolor-ios10/40255483#40255483

Comment: @Joe this doesn't help!

Comment: So the issue persists without animation?